Flutter String Concat and String Interpolation Error
I am trying to concat two strings ('  @' + list[index]['user_name']) but I am getting the String Interpolation error. Here is the error I am getting:
Use interpolation to compose strings and values.
Try using string interpolation to build the composite string.
Here is my code snippet:
Flexible(
   child: Text(
              '  @' + list[index]['user_name'],
              maxLines: 3,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600]),
            ),
),

How do I rwewrite this so that the error message can go away?

You can do this '  @${list[index]['user_name']}',

try this using string interpolation instead:
Flexible(
          child: Text(
            ' @${list[index]['user_name']}',
            maxLines: 3,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600]),
          ),
        ),

